# Javascript, match checkboxes with JSON

Tags: javascript, json, checkbox, lookup

I have:

- A number of checkboxes
- A button to submit
- A JSON string object.
- A function to check which checkboxes are checked, and return their values in an alert or console.log with an evenlistener on my submit-button.
- An output DIV

How can I compare the values I get from the function that checks which checkboxes are checked to the values in the JSON string object, and echo them into the output DIV? Say I check the "Cheese" and "Garlic" boxes, and expect to receive the following output:

- Recipe1: Cheese, Tomato, Garlic
- Recipe2: Cheese, Potato, Mayo, Beef, Garlic, Butter

**The HTML:**

```
<form action="" method="">
    <input type="checkbox" value="Cheese">Cheese<br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Tomato">Tomato<br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Garlic">Garlic<br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Bacon">Bacon<br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Paprika">Paprika<br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Onion">Onion<br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Potato">Potato<br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Mayo">Mayo<br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Beef">Beef<br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Garlic">Garlic<br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Butter">Butter<br>

    <input type="button" value="Get recipes" id="getRecipesButton">
</form>

<div id="output">The results end up here</div>
```

**The JS:**

```
//Recipes JSON-string:
var recipes = [
    {
        name:"recipe1",
        ingredients:
            [
                {ingredient:"Cheese"},
                {ingredient:"Tomato"},
                {ingredient:"Garlic"}
            ]
    },
    {
        name:"recipe2",
        ingredients:
            [
                {ingredient:"Cheese"},
                {ingredient:"Bacon"},
                {ingredient:"Paprika"},
                {ingredient:"Onion"}
            ]
    },
    {
        name:"recipe3",
        ingredients:
            [
                {ingredient:"Cheese"},
                {ingredient:"Potato"},
                {ingredient:"Mayo"},
                {ingredient:"Beef"},
                {ingredient:"Garlic"},
                {ingredient:"Butter"}
            ]
    }
];
//Test to retrieve single, specific entries: 
//      console.log(recipes[1].ingredients[0].ingredient);


//Test to get/return the checked values of the checkboxes:
function selectedBoxes(form) {
    let selectedBoxesArr = [];
    let inputFields = form.getElementsByTagName('input');
    let inputFieldsNumber = inputFields.length;

    for(let i=0; i<inputFieldsNumber; i++) {
        if(
            inputFields[i].type == 'checkbox' &&
            inputFields[i].checked == true
        ) selectedBoxesArr.push(inputFields[i].value);
    }
    return selectedBoxesArr;
}

var getRecipesButton = document.getElementById('getRecipesButton');
getRecipesButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
    let selectedCheckBoxes = selectedBoxes(this.form);
    alert(selectedCheckBoxes);
});
```

[>>Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z6dbfaus/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter your array of recipes to only the recipes that includes all the select ingredients, like this:

```
let filtered = recipes.filter((recipe) => {
    return selectedCheckBoxes.every((selected) => {
        return recipe.ingredients.some((ingredient) => {
            return ingredient['ingredient'] === selected;
        });
    });
});
```

So, for each one of the recipes we check if **every** selected ingredient is contained in the recipe. In this case:

- *filter():* Filters out any recipe that does not contain every selected ingredient;
- *every():* Checks if every select ingredient is in the current recipe being evaluated by filter();
- *some():* Checks if some of the recipe's ingredients is equal to the current select ingredient being evaluated by every().

I edited your fiddle so you can see it working: https://jsfiddle.net/byce6vwu/1/

**Edit**

You can convert the returned array to html like this (i also changed the output div to an *ul*:

```
let outputRecipes = '';
  filtered.forEach((recipe) => {
    let stringIngredients = recipe.ingredients.map((val) => {
        return val.ingredient;
    }).join(',');
        outputRecipes += `<li>${recipe.name}: ${stringIngredients}</li>`;
  });
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = outputRecipes;
```

I've edited the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ys0qofgm/

So, for each ingredient in the array, we convert the ingredient object: `{ingredient: "Cheese"}` to only a string *"Cheese"* and join all the elements of the array using a comma as the separator. Then create a *li* element for each recipe, and put the recipe string inside of it.

Comment: Thanks! As it returned arrays I have not selected this as the solution, though it absolutely does what I was looking for to some extent. I've upvoted it, as it _is_ useful and has taught me something!

Comment: Any suggestion on how to output the array and the inner array that is returned?

Comment: I've edited the answer with how to do what you want.

Comment: Great! Can't thank you enough. Now I have much better tools to study how to make something like this myself.

Answer (score 2):

What do you think about this quick suggestion, I know it's not very elegant:

#### HTML (replace with this)

```
<ul id="output">The results end up here</ul>
```

#### JS

```
var getRecipesButton = document.getElementById('getRecipesButton');
getRecipesButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
    let selectedCheckBoxes = selectedBoxes(this.form);
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "";
  var res = [];
  recipes.forEach(function(r,k){
    r['ingredients'].forEach(function(i,idx){
        if(selectedCheckBoxes.includes(i.ingredient)) {
        res.push(r);
      }
    });
  });
// remove duplicate then display the recipe with the ingredient
    res.filter(function(item, index){
      return res.indexOf(item) >= index;
    }).forEach(function(r){
      var ingredient = r.ingredients.map(function(r) { return r.ingredient}).join(", ");
      var name = r.name + " : "+ingredient ;
      var ul = document.getElementById("output");
      var li = document.createElement('li');
      li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(name));
      ul.appendChild(li);
    });
});
```

Here a working version: https://jsfiddle.net/8esvh65p/

Comment: Great! That absolutely did the trick. The other answers returned arrays (i.e. not a complete solution). I get the value of the other answers too though and I may use them if I need to change the functionality. I also adjusted the submit-button to be invisible (zero height, width, padding and margin), and wrapped it in an eventlistener for the checkboxes instead, so whenever someone checks or unchecks a box, it will update instantly.

Comment: You're welcome. Btw, I'm sure we can "optimize" the code but maybe for later.

Comment: perhaps. I honestly think it's pretty short and neat as it is. But I'll be working with this for a while as it will serve as my personal recipe lookup for shopping based on the ingredients I have at hand, so I'm sure I'll find myself in situations where I would want or need to update it along the way (that's usually the case with most things).

Answer (score 2):

This code will do what you want. It iterates over each ingredient, checking the set of recipes and their ingredients to check if that recipe includes that ingredient. Only recipes which include **all** the selected ingredients are returned:

```js
//Recipes JSON-string:
var recipes = [
 {
  name:"recipe1",
  ingredients:
   [
    {ingredient:"Cheese"},
    {ingredient:"Tomato"},
    {ingredient:"Garlic"}
   ]
 },
 {
  name:"recipe2",
  ingredients:
   [
    {ingredient:"Cheese"},
    {ingredient:"Bacon"},
    {ingredient:"Paprika"},
    {ingredient:"Onion"}
   ]
 },
 {
  name:"recipe3",
  ingredients:
   [
    {ingredient:"Cheese"},
    {ingredient:"Potato"},
    {ingredient:"Mayo"},
    {ingredient:"Beef"},
    {ingredient:"Garlic"},
    {ingredient:"Butter"}
   ]
 }
];
//Test to retrieve single, specific entries:
//      console.log(recipes[1].ingredients[0].ingredient);


//Test to get/return the checked values of the checkboxes:
function selectedBoxes(form) {
 let selectedBoxesArr = [];
 let inputFields = form.getElementsByTagName('input');
 let inputFieldsNumber = inputFields.length;

 for(let i=0; i<inputFieldsNumber; i++) {
  if(
   inputFields[i].type == 'checkbox' &&
   inputFields[i].checked == true
  ) selectedBoxesArr.push(inputFields[i].value);
 }
 return selectedBoxesArr;
}

var getRecipesButton = document.getElementById('getRecipesButton');
getRecipesButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
  let selectedCheckBoxes = selectedBoxes(this.form);
  let output = document.getElementById('output');
  let myRecipes = recipes.filter(r => 
    selectedCheckBoxes.every(s => 
       r.ingredients.some(i => i.ingredient == s)
    )
  );
  output.innerHTML = myRecipes.map(v => v.name + ': ' + v.ingredients.map(i => i.ingredient).join(', ')).join('<br>');
});
```

```html
<form action="" method="">
 <input type="checkbox" value="Cheese">Cheese<br>
 <input type="checkbox" value="Tomato">Tomato<br>
 <input type="checkbox" value="Garlic">Garlic<br>
 <input type="checkbox" value="Bacon">Bacon<br>
 <input type="checkbox" value="Paprika">Paprika<br>
 <input type="checkbox" value="Onion">Onion<br>
 <input type="checkbox" value="Potato">Potato<br>
 <input type="checkbox" value="Mayo">Mayo<br>
 <input type="checkbox" value="Beef">Beef<br>
 <input type="checkbox" value="Garlic">Garlic<br>
 <input type="checkbox" value="Butter">Butter<br>

 <input type="button" value="Get recipes" id="getRecipesButton">
</form>

<div id="output">The results end up here</div>
```

Comment: Great! This works though it doesn't output the ingredients and only outputs one that matches, not all.

Comment: @Strechingmycompetence sorry about that - I didn't read the question carefully enough. Just for completeness I have updated the answer to give the output you requested.

Comment: No stress!  I'm loving the variety of approaches to this. It gives me hope about my future and motivation to continue learning :D

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way you can set the values based on your current structure. Keep in mind, it is not clear what recipe you would like to apply at any given time, so the code below will apply the first recipe to the form.

```js
//Recipes JSON-string:
var recipes = [{
    name: "recipe1",
    ingredients: [{
        ingredient: "Cheese"
      },
      {
        ingredient: "Tomato"
      },
      {
        ingredient: "Garlic"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "recipe2",
    ingredients: [{
        ingredient: "Cheese"
      },
      {
        ingredient: "Bacon"
      },
      {
        ingredient: "Paprika"
      },
      {
        ingredient: "Onion"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "recipe3",
    ingredients: [{
        ingredient: "Cheese"
      },
      {
        ingredient: "Potato"
      },
      {
        ingredient: "Mayo"
      },
      {
        ingredient: "Beef"
      },
      {
        ingredient: "Garlic"
      },
      {
        ingredient: "Butter"
      }
    ]
  }
];

var getRecipesButton = document.getElementById('getRecipesButton');
getRecipesButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  for (let ingredient of recipes[0].ingredients) {
    document.querySelector(`input[value='${ingredient.ingredient}']`).setAttribute('checked', true);
  }
});
```

```html
<form action="" method="">
  <input type="checkbox" value="Cheese">Cheese<br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="Tomato">Tomato<br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="Garlic">Garlic<br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="Bacon">Bacon<br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="Paprika">Paprika<br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="Onion">Onion<br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="Potato">Potato<br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="Mayo">Mayo<br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="Beef">Beef<br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="Garlic">Garlic<br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="Butter">Butter<br>

  <input type="button" value="Get recipes" id="getRecipesButton">
</form>

<div id="output">The results end up here</div>
```

*Feel free to comment if you have any questions*

Answer (score 1):

I edited your code and made it smaller and also added `getRecipe` that will return the recipes.

```js
//Recipes JSON-string:
var recipes = [
    {
        name:"recipe1",
        ingredients:
            [
                {ingredient:"Cheese"},
                {ingredient:"Tomato"},
                {ingredient:"Garlic"}
            ]
    },
    {
        name:"recipe2",
        ingredients:
            [
                {ingredient:"Cheese"},
                {ingredient:"Bacon"},
                {ingredient:"Paprika"},
                {ingredient:"Onion"}
            ]
    },
    {
        name:"recipe3",
        ingredients:
            [
                {ingredient:"Cheese"},
                {ingredient:"Potato"},
                {ingredient:"Mayo"},
                {ingredient:"Beef"},
                {ingredient:"Garlic"},
                {ingredient:"Butter"}
            ]
    }
];

function selectedBoxes(form) {
    let selectedBoxesArr = [];
    let inputFields = form.getElementsByTagName('input');
    // get all checked input values
    var checked = [...inputFields].filter((item) => item.checked == true
    ).map((item) => item.value)
    return checked;
}

// Validate the checked ingredients and get the recipes
function getRecipe(ingredients){
var recipe = [];
recipes.forEach((item)=> {
var found= false;
for(var ingredient in ingredients){
   var y = ingredients[ingredient]
   found= item.ingredients.filter((x) =>  x.ingredient.indexOf(y) != -1).length>0;
  if (!found)
      break;
    }
  if(found)
     recipe.push(item.name +":"+ item.ingredients.map((x)=> x.ingredient).join(", "));
});
return recipe;
}

var getRecipesButton = document.getElementById('getRecipesButton');
getRecipesButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
    let selectedCheckBoxes = selectedBoxes(this.form);
    console.log(getRecipe(selectedCheckBoxes))
});
```

```html
<form action="" method="">
    <input type="checkbox" value="Cheese">Cheese<br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Tomato">Tomato<br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Garlic">Garlic<br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Bacon">Bacon<br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Paprika">Paprika<br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Onion">Onion<br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Potato">Potato<br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Mayo">Mayo<br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Beef">Beef<br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Garlic">Garlic<br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Butter">Butter<br>

    <input type="button" value="Get recipes" id="getRecipesButton">
</form>

<div id="output">The results end up here</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I've upvoted your answer, as it _is_ useful and has taught me something, though it only seems to return the first recipe it finds and arrays for the rest.